# Sorting serialized data - Django - getting keyerror

Tags: python, django

Version Info:

```
Django: 1.11.2
Python 2.7
```

In my application, I want to sort by a field in the data that is returned by the serializer, however, it is throwing an error.

The resultset is of type `rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers.ReturnList`, the data is given below (only sample, actual data is pretty huge).

```
    [OrderedDict([(u'id', 941), 
    ('business_location', {'distance': 3.7249839781687317, 'business': 941, u'id': 916}), 
    ('business_detail', {'business_profile': u"Good solutions!", 'website': None}), 
    ('business_images', []), 
    ('business_service', [OrderedDict([(u'id', 1587), 
    ('length_of_slots', 12), 
    ('price', 25.0), 
    ('business_group', None)])]),
    ('premium', False) 
    ]),
    OrderedDict([(u'id', 1595), 
    ('business_location', {'distance': 6.376269428282773, 'business': 1595, u'id': 1634}), 
    ('business_detail', {'business_profile': u'A long-term wellness.', 'website': None}), 
    ('business_images', []), 
    ('business_service', [OrderedDict([(u'id', 5361), 
    ('length_of_booking_slot', u''), 
    ('price', 125.0), 
    ('business_group', None)])]),
    ('premium', True) 
    ])]
```

The error I'm getting is `(KeyError('price',), 'price')`

The views.py, I'm using this code to sort by price.

```
sorted(business_serializer.data, key=lambda k: (k['price']))
```

Kindly suggest what is that I'm doing wrong. Also, I would want to implement ASC/DESC functionality.

Note: I tried to implement `order_by` in the serializer, since my data has a different category & each of them will have a price it is not getting sorted at the result level.

**Edit: Edited the response (premium key added), Added below lines**

Since the price is located within business_service, I tried

```
sorted(business_serializer.data, key=lambda k: (k['business_service']['price']))
```

I'm getting this error `(TypeError('list indices must be integers, not str',), 'list indices must be integers, not str')`

Also the existing code of `sorted(business_serializer.data, key=lambda k: (-k['premium']))` is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the data example you provide the value associated to `'business_service'` is a `list`, thus the `TypeError` when your write:

```py
sorted(business_serializer.data, key=lambda k: (k['business_service']['price']))
```

You need to access the `OrderedDict` in the list returned by `k['business_service']` before you can access the key `'price'`.

So **this should work**:

```py
sorted(business_serializer.data, key=lambda k: (k['business_service'][0]['price']))
```

---

*FYI: Both, django 1.11, as well as python 2.7 are critically outdated.*

Comment: I was under an impression that having an index 0 would not loop through the entire list of objects, hence left it. However, it worked. Any references on lambda, most of the search points to some basic examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the default Object Manager of a model. Writing your Custom Object Manager you can modify the queryset returned by the query.

DOCS here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/

Comment: This is an existing application & I cannot modify anything that changes the object bcoz a front-end application is dependent on this data.